# django-zappa: Error loading psycopg2 module: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa

When trying to deploy a Django project using django-zappa, I get the following error in the `zappa tail` output:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've made sure to include the psycopg2 module in the requirements file:

```
psycopg2==2.8.3
```

It's installed   in the virtual environment that's active while running the zappa deploy command.

I'm running on Linux and had to install `libpq-dev` via apt before even being able to `pip install psycopg2` as I received an error before, saying that libpq was missing on the system (similar to the above error, I guess).

How can I overcome this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your Pipenv file?

Comment: Actually, I'm using virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by installing the psycopg2-binary package:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

After a redeploy, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when runing django in a raspberrypi model 3 B+ with the latest os.

```
sudo  apt-get install libpq5 -y
```

worked for me